# How to validate a form for all browsers including mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website http://www.yaseennikah.com/MyRegister.php. I need to validate the form on the client side. I used javascript code, but it is not working in some mobile browsers. I saw a jquery code here http://jsfiddle.net/WF2J9/16/. But I don't know to add jquery ul. So can any one complete the code please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>form validation</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="page1.php" method="post" class="a">
    Name : <input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="name" /> <br/>
    Address : <input type="text" class="text" name="address" id="address /><br/>
    email : <input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email" /> <br/>
      <button id="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    valid = true;   

    if (valid && $('#name').val() == '') {
        alert ("please enter your name");
        valid = false;
    }

    if (valid && $('#address').val() == '') {
        alert ("please enter your address");
         valid = false;
    }    

    return valid;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add jQuery to your web page using their official CDNs 
Add this to the head of your web page `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>`

And you can test if jQuery was loaded correctly using this code

```
if($) {
  alert("jQuery loaded");
} else {
  alert("jQuery not loaded");
}
```

**Edit:** 
Here is my version of the [validation script](https://jsfiddle.net/aqos156/yp54dwdh/3/) (now should be working) and don't forget to remove the `trim()` function if you don't want it.

**Edit 2:** 
If you want to do this without jQuery, you can use html's automatic form validation [example](https://jsfiddle.net/aqos156/fttbt9aw/). But this is not supported in ie 9 and earlier. 
Or you can try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/aqos156/gs8vtxaj/) (Rewritten jQuery code from above to pure js and a second way of form validation).
**Validate the form on server's side too !!!**

Comment: it is showing jQuery loaded. But code the previous code not working.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to update it, now everything should be good https://jsfiddle.net/aqos156/yp54dwdh/3/

Comment: is not possiple to do without jquery api ?

Comment: And btw, could you give me the arrow up (thumb up) ?

Comment: You might want to double-check if the required attribute works on Safari.

Comment: i have a one more question here as above at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190792/how-to-validate-a-forms-input-from-ajax-page-using-jquery. please can you answer it.