# How to validate a form's input from ajax page using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

There are two inputs in my form. The first input can be validated before an ajax function. The second input can't be validated. The second input comes from a page using ajax and the submit button also comes from the page using ajax. I need to validate the second input which comes from the page using ajax. Also the submit button which comes from the page is not working. Please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form").submit(function(){   
          if ($('#Name1').val().length<3) {
            alert ("please enter your first names");
            $('#Name1').focus();
            return false;
          }
          $.ajax({
            url: "result.php",
            method: "GET" // Either get or post
          }).done(function(response) {
            var splitted = response.split("|"); // RESULT
            $("#Div1").html(splitted[0]); // The first name
            $("#Div2").html(splitted[1]); // The first name
          });
          return (false);

          if ($('#Name2').val().length<3) {
            alert ("please enter your second names");
            $('#Name2').focus();
            return false;
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form" action="Page.php">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <b>Name1:</b>
      </div>
      <input id="Name1" type="text">
      <br><br><br><br>
      <div style="clear:both;">
        <div style="float:left;">
          <b>Name2:</b>
        </div>
        <div id="Div1" style="float:left;">
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
        <div style="clear:both;">
          <div id="Div2">
            <button>First Event</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is result.php

```
<input type="text" id="Name2">  
    i need to validate this input. | <button>Second Event</button>
```

Comment: will you second event be submited in page.php??

Comment: yes. but before form submission i want to validate

Comment: can you help me sir.

Comment: I used to code to simulate what you want to do. You did many mistakes. 
1- The submition of the second event does nothing but doing the what the previous did. Do you want a new code or a correction of your code??

Comment: The submission of the second event and first event are doing same thing. this is what i want. i need to implement in my website.

Comment: Hey man, i've edited your question. Please check it because i've cahnged the html tags, because they were not closed at the end. I don't know if i've got it right. Also please check the wording in your question. I've changed that too soo please correct it if you find any mistaken words.

Comment: Describe what you want to do one more time, please. What you want to validate. What you want to do after the validation etc..

Comment: i want to validate the second input which is comes from ajax page (result.php). after validation complete the form should be submitted.  what are confusing more in this question. it is very simple question.

Comment: if you have new code also you can deliver here. But it should be same functionality as above.

Comment: So how am i supposed to validate the second input ? Using what, length of the input ?

Comment: and why do you need to get the second input from the result.php page?

Comment: yes,  validate second input using length of input. For verification code purpose i call second input from result.php. please correct the code and give the right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works well. i have solved myself.

```
<html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#form").submit(function(){  

              if ($('#Name1').val().length<3) {
                alert ("please enter your first names");
                $('#Name1').focus();
                return false;
              }

              if ($('#hidden').val().length<3) {
                  $.ajax({
                    url: "result.php",
                    method: "GET" // Either get or post
                        }).done(function(response) {
                        var splitted = response.split("|"); // RESULT
                            $("#Div1").html(splitted[0]); // The first name
                            $("#Div2").html(splitted[1]); // The first name

                        });
                    //alert ("please verify");
                     return false;
                    }

                if ($('#Name2').val().length<3) {
                    alert ("please enter your second names");
                    $('#Name2').focus();
                     return false;
                }


            });
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form id="form" action="Page.php">
          <div style="float:left;">
            <b>Name1:</b>
          </div>
          <input id="Name1" type="text">
          <br><br><br><br>
          <div style="clear:both;">
            <div style="float:left;">
              <b>Name2:</b>
            </div>
            <div id="Div1" style="float:left;">
              <input id="hidden" type="hidden">
            </div>
            <br><br><br>
            <div style="clear:both;">
              <div id="Div2">
                <button>First Event</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

result.php

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="something"> <input type="text" id="Name2"> | <input id="button" type="submit" value="Second Event">
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can do this, however because I am on my phone I can't give you a detailed example.

What I recommend for you to look into is sending the AJAX request as JSON data to your PHP file, you can then validate the JSON data within the PHP file and return a response to the front end accordingly.

Within the PHP file you can return any value as a response, meaning that if you echo "success" or "true", you can see whether the data is what you are looking to receive from the user.

I would highly recommend doing as much validation possible in the back end. It is a good habit to get in to as anything can be manipulated on the front end of a website.

Comment: i don't have much knowledge to validate in back end. please just explain to validate in the front end.

Comment: There's no point in using AJAX if you don't intend on validating anything in the back end though? You could simply check the values on the front end e.g. if('.something').val().length == 0) { alert("enter something") }. But again, this could easily be manipulated as there is no PHP validation, if you were doing something more important I could change the '== 0' to '!== 0' and not have to input anything.

Comment: after submission i can validate in php file. But here i need to validate before submission.